# Vue2: passing function as prop triggers warning that prop is already set

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Vue and I am so far enjoying the Single File Components.

Prior to making what I really want to make, I figured I would try some small things to see if I grasp the concept.

So I set off to make a component for opening an XMLHttpRequest, with a progress bar.

[image]

```
<template >
  <div  v-if="showQ">
    <div class="text-muted">
      <span>{{humanReadableLead}}</span>
      <span :class="'text-'+color">{{humanReadableMessage}}</span>
      <span>{{humanReadableEnd}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div
        class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated"
        :class="'bg-'+color"
        role="progressbar"
        :style="{width: String(percent)+'%'}"
        :aria-valuenow="percent"
        aria-valuemin="0"
        aria-valuemax="100"
      ></div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-right text-muted form-text text-small">
      <span class="float-left">{{xhrMessage}}</span>
      <span
        class="badge"
        :class="'badge-'+color"
        data-toggle="tooltip"
        data-placement="right"
        :title="readyStateTooltip"
        >
          {{xhr.readyState}}
        </span>
      <span
        class="badge"
        :class="'badge-'+color"
        data-toggle="tooltip"
        data-placement="right"
        :title="statusTooltip"
      >
        {{xhr.status}}
      </span>
      <span
        v-if="transferComplete"
        @click="goodbye"
        class="badge badge-secondary"
        data-toggle="tooltip"
        data-placement="right"
        title="Dismiss progress bar"
      >
        &times;
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>

import {httpStatusCodes, httpReadyStateCodes} from './http-responses';

export default {
  props: {
    method: {
      type: String,
      default: "GET",
      validator: function(value) {
        return ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"].includes(value)
      }
    },
    url: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    async: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    success: {
      type: Function,
      default: function() {
        console.log(this.xhr.response)
      }
    },
    readystatechange: {
      type: Function,
      default: function(event) {
      }
    },
    automaticCloseQ: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      xhr: new XMLHttpRequest(),
      httpStatusCodes:httpStatusCodes,
      httpReadyStateCodes:httpReadyStateCodes,
      color: "primary",
      percent: 0,
      humanReadableLead: "",
      humanReadableMessage: "",
      humanReadableEnd: "",
      xhrMessage: "",
      showQ: true,
      completeQ: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    readyStateTooltip: function() {
      var rs = this.xhr.readyState,
      rsc = httpReadyStateCodes[rs]
      return `Ready state ${rs}: ${rsc}`
    },
    statusTooltip: function() {
      var s = this.xhr.status
      // s = s == 0 ? 218 : s
      var sc = httpStatusCodes[s]
      return `Status ${s}: ${sc}`
    },
    transferComplete: function() {
      return this.completeQ
    }
  },
  methods: {
    open: function() {
      this.xhr.open(this.method, this.url, this.async)
    },
    send: function() {
      this.xhr.send()
    },
    goodbye: function() {
      this.showQ = false
    }
  },

  created: function() {
    var that = this
    that.open()

    that.xhr.addEventListener("error", function(event) {
      that.color = "danger"
      that.xhrMessage = "An error has occured."
    })

    this.xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(event) {
      if (event.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = event.loaded / event.total * 100;
        that.percent = percentComplete
      } else {
        that.percent = 100
        that.xhrMessage = "Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown."
      }
    })

    that.xhr.addEventListener("abort", function(event) {
      that.color = "danger"
      that.xhrMessage = "The transfer has been canceled by the user."
    });

    that.xhr.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
      that.color = "success"
      that.xhrMessage = "Transfer complete."
      that.completeQ = true
      if (that.automaticCloseQ) { that.showQ = false }
      that.success()
    })

    that.xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(event) {
      that.readystatechange(event)
    })

    that.send()
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

and in **index.html**

```
<div id="request" style="width:50%;" >
  <http-request :url="'./<some-file>'"/>
</div>
```

with JS

```
var progress = new Vue({
  el: '#request',
  components: { httpRequest }
})
```

and this works fairly nicely...

However, there are a few small bugs that for the life of me I can not figure out:

- I would like to define a function `onSuccess` that I pass to the prop `success`, but this throws an error from Vue
- the computed properties for `statusTooltip` does not get updated
- trying to set `automaticCloseQ` results in the default value no matter how I try to bind

e.g.

```
var onSuccess = function() {console.log('here')}

<http-request :url="'./<some-file>'" :success="onSuccess" :automaticCloseQ="true"/>
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

*I would like to define a function onSuccess that I pass to the prop success, but this throws an error from Vue*

You are defining `onSuccess` outside of Vue. It should be defined in Vue's `methods`

---

*the computed properties for statusTooltip does not get updated*

In Javascript, an object is passed by reference. `xhr` always reference the same object. That's why the computed value won't update. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats . 1 way to solve it is to have another reactive data called `xhrStatus` and update this status manually in the xhr's event listeners.

---

*trying to set automaticCloseQ results in the default value no matter how I try to bind*

(I dunno what this means...)

Comment: So there is no way to pass an arbitrarily named function defined outside of Vue to Vue as a prop unless the same arbitrary name is inside vue? That seems silly... What if I want 3 instances with functions `onSuccessCallback1`, `onSuccessCallback2`, `onSuccessCallback3`? Then I can't generalize my component?

Comment: I wanted to add a toggle for the behavior of the component `automaticCloseQ` which would either - after successful transfer - automatically remove the element (not the vue instance) , or show the vue instance with the close button. I defined a boolean prop with default false (which it is anyway for boolean values), and then tried `:automaticCloseQ="true"` and no matter what (e.g. v-bind, no `:`, etc) I could not get `automaticCloseQ` to be set to true